# How to handle multiple value to store for multiple user?

Tags: mysql, laravel

This is my html table

```
Checkbox    | Name
Checkbox    | abc
Checkbox    | efg
Checkbox    | xyz
```

-

```
//checkbox is an array 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="id_franchise[]" value="{{ $item->id_franchise}}"></td>

//POST data
array:3 [▼
  0 => "11"
  1 => "53"
  2 => "10"
]
```

E.g. franchise id 11 and 53 is belong to user id 100 while franchise id 10 is belong to user id 200.

My database

```
user_id | franchise_id
100     |   11 
100     |   53
100     |   54
100     |   56
200     |   10
200     |   15
```

In my database i want it to be stored in another table column name item_assigned as

```
id   | user_id | vendor_id | franchise_assigned
1    |  100    |     1     | 11,53
2    |  200    |     2     | 10
```

When the user click submit to store the data, it will check the franchise_assigned column whether the franchise id existed or not by looping to compare between existed and submitted data.

I faced problem on storing the franchies based on user to the column. How can i write the function and query in my controller to store the data into database?

Comment: Storing ids as a comma separated list in your database with the expectation of querying and updating them is crazy. You're using a relational database for a reason. So start creating relationships. Look at the Laravel [relationships docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships). I think you need either a one-to-many or many-to-many. And there are helper functions for creating and updating these relationships.

Comment: Also, if you already have a relationship between `user_id` and `franchise_id`, why do you need `franchise_assigned`?

Comment: @fubar Kind of status for vendor_id.

Comment: Well, I think you should create a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship. I don't understand your database structure to be able to help any further.

Comment: @fubar i knew it is crazy and bad practice on doing this, but i just follow as requested, i have no right to change database structure. What i think is just when storing the franchise id, how can i split it based on user id.

Comment: Give me the table names and relationships

Comment: @MahdiYounesi The first table is franchise, second is user_vendor. One user may consist of many franchise and one franchise only belong to one user. In user_vendor table. One user may connect to many vendor, and one vendor has many user. I am trying to save franchise_id that belong to user in franchise_assigned column.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that your relationship table name is `item_assigned` and its corresponding model name is `ItemAssigned`. You could solve your problem with some simple steps.

First, You could check for existent record with `user_id` like -

```
$items = ItemAssigned::where('user_id',$your_user_id_you_want_to_insert_record_for)->first();
```

I assume you have only one entry record for a single user in this table. Or Further one entry record for `user_id` and `vendor_id` combined. If later is the case then you could do something -

```
$items = ItemAssigned::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('vendor_id',$vendor_id)->first();
```

Now you want to store `francise_id` by checking whether it already exists or not. To do that you need to grab `franchise_assigned` and parse it and check like the following -

```
if($items!=null){
    $franchise_assigned = $items->franchise_assigned;
    $ar = (explode(",",$franchise_assigned));

    $ar = array_replace($ar,array_fill_keys(array_keys($ar, $francise_id_to_check), $francise_id_to_be_replaced_by));
  }
}
```

If you need to remove old value and add new value, then create a new array and append every value that is not old value. After that add new value.

```
$new_ar = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($ar as $a){
    if($a!=$old_francise_value)
       $new_ar[$count++] = $a;
}
$new_ar[$count++] = $new_francise_value;
```

At last merge it again with comma separated value -

```
$franchise_assigned_new = implode(",",$ar);
```

And update it-

```
$items->franchise_assigned = $franchise_assigned_new;
$items->save();
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: ItemAssigned is not a table, it is an attribute in a table that connect user and vendor.

Comment: i just assume it, you replace it with your own

Comment: I expected result is if  franchise_assigned value = 11,53 , when user assign for the next time, user select again franchise id 11 and new franchise id 18, then the franchise id 11 will be removed and id 18 will be saved, then the column value became 53,18